# Sudden data corruption of local variable

Tags: c, pointers, corruption

I am concatenating few strings using a custom function. The functions works correctly and I get the proper values but after few statements the values in the char pointers gets corrupted. I do not understand the reason behind this. Below is the part of a larger function. I am just providing the code till where the corruption happens

```
char* my_strcpy(char*dest, const char* src, int hasLen, int length) {
    if (!hasLen) {
        while ((*dest = *src++))
            ++dest;

    } else {
        while (length-- && (*dest = *src++))
            ++dest;
    }
    return dest;
}
int addSubscriptionInCache(subs_t* subs, str* pres_uri, int read_response) {

    redisReply *reply;

    char temp_key[1] = "";
    char *tk = my_strcpy(temp_key, "", 0, 0);
    char *subs_cache_key = tk;

    char temp_value[1] = "";
    char *tv = my_strcpy(temp_value, "", 0, 0);
    char *subs_cache_value = tv;

    tk = my_strcpy(tk, SUBSCRIPTION_SET_PREFIX, 0, 0);
    tk = my_strcpy(tk, "-", 0, 0);
    tk = my_strcpy(tk, subs->pres_uri.s, 0, 0);
    tk = my_strcpy(tk, ":", 0, 0);
    tk = my_strcpy(tk, subs->event->name.s, 0, 0);
    *tk = '\0';

    // this prints correctly.
    printf("subs_cache_key: %d %s \n", strlen(subs_cache_key), subs_cache_key);

    int subs_cache_value_len = subs->callid.len + subs->to_tag.len + 1; // add 1 for :

    tv = my_strcpy(tv, subs->to_tag.s, 1,subs->to_tag.len);
    tv = my_strcpy(tv, ":", 0, 0);
    tv = my_strcpy(tv, subs->callid.s, 1,subs->callid.len);
    *tv= '\0';
    // this prints correctly.
    printf("subs_cache_value: %d %s \n", strlen(subs_cache_value), subs_cache_value);

    //add in pipeline
    redisAppendCommand(redis_context, "SADD %s %s", subs_cache_key, subs_cache_value))
    //set expires
    redisAppendCommand(redis_context, "EXPIRE %s %d", subs_cache_key, subs->expires);

    // create hash for to_tag:call_id
    int argc = 0;
    char *arvg[22];
    size_t argvlen[22];
    // this prints fine.
    printf("Before corruption: %s", subs_cache_value);
    arvg[argc] = "HMSET";
    // below prints corrupted values
    printf("After corruption: %s", subs_cache_value);
    printf("After corruption: %s", subs_cache_key);
    argvlen[argc] = 5;
    argc++;

    arvg[argc] = subs_cache_value;
    argvlen[argc] = subs_cache_value_len;
    argc++;

    .......
    //rest of the code
    }
```

I am using the custom function so that not to traverse the whole string again and again.

Please help me understand if I have done something because of which corruption is happening.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to debug your program using memory debugger? Such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: Now, after reading the code. You do not assign your strings anywhere? You are using a single char `temp_value[1]` to hold the strings. You must allocate them or use big enough buffer.

Comment: I am not able to use valgrind with this. Actually, this is a server code and executes only when it receives a request but when I use this with valgrind, valgrind does not wait for the request and exits just by executing on init functions.

Comment: You need underlying string arrays for your strings. `tk` is the tail pointer of an empty string written to a one-element char array. Later, you append more data where there is no space.

Comment: Your are creating strings with a certain pattern. The task may be easier with, for example, `snprintf(tv, sizeof(tv), "%s:%s", subs->to_tag.s, subs->callid.s)`, where `tv` is an appropriately sized char array. `snprintf` will also guard against buffer overflow.

Comment: @MOehm Earlier I was using snprintf but I found some bad performance from the code. I did few tests and found that custom method takes half the CPU time that of snprintf.

Comment: I didn't know you operated under such tight time constraints. `snprintf` needs to scan the format string, of course and also do the necessary checks to guard against buffer overflow.

Comment: @MOehm Actually, I have modified an existing open source project and immediately encountered real bad performance. I am not able to run profilers on this code as mentioned in above comment. I just suspect snprintf to be culprit, so, just trying to improve that.

Comment: @MOehm Oh!! you are correct, now I am surprised too that why I didn't used the buffer I had for snprintf. Don't know what I was thinking and absolutely, slow running code is still better than failing fast code :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
char temp_key[1] = "";
char *tk = my_strcpy(temp_key, "", 0, 0);
```

and go on to use `tk` in subsequent calls to `my_strcpy`.

The problem is that you don't have enough memory. Using memory beyond the valid limits leads to undefined behavior.

Use something like:

```
char temp_key[1000] = "";  // Make the size large enough for
                           // the kinds of strings you are 
                           // expecting to see.
```

Similarly, use:

```
char temp_value[1000] = "";
```

Comment: Thats very stupid of me. I thought tk and temp_key point to different mem location and I can add as much to tk. Still lot to learn.

Comment: @user3275095, don't feel too bad. Most of use have made pretty stupid mistakes along the way.